# Problem with Micro SD card breakout

Tags: arduino-uno

I was connecting my arduino uno to a adafruif micro SD card breakout and everything worked just fine, i could read the sd, write to it and see all the info about it. To do it i just followed the tutorial in [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-micro-sd-breakout-board-card-tutorial/library?view=all).

My problem is that when I arrived home the exact some thing wouldn't work and I couldn't read the SD card anymore.

I was thinking it could be a bad contact problem since sometimes i get:

```
Initializing SD card...initialization failed. Things to check:
* is a card inserted?
* is your wiring correct?
* did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?
```

And other times (almost never), i would just get:

```
Initializing SD card...Wiring is correct and a card is present.
Card type: SD2
Could not find FAT16/FAT32 partition.
Make sure you've formatted the card
```

I would like to know if I can assume it is the breakout board failling and I would buy a new one, or if it can be any other thing.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

1. Reading the SD card in your computer ... if  you can read (or write) files, that means the SD card is intact
2. Use a SD card that worked before or similar. Some bigger SD cards (like SDHC, SDXC have less good compatibility). Preferably use a 2 GB or smaller card (unless you have used bigger cards successfully and of the same or smaller type, e.g. SD, SDHC, SDXC).
3. Try different formattings, like FAT, FAT16, FAT32. I think FAT is the mostly recognized formatting.
4. Check connections/wires to/from SD breakout, maybe during your leave accidentally you (or someone else) or due to pressure/tension, a contact/wire got loose.
5. Check another SD card in the SD breakout where the SD card you know is good. If this also does not work, it must be the breakout (or Arduino).
6. Replace every piece of hardware (including wires) one by one and recheck if it works (after you are sure the SD card itself is ok).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes i tried a new sd card that i just bought for this and still nothing, and i also formated both cards to fat32 (they are 8 GB), and both of them work on my laptop. I remade alreadythe wiring a thousand times with new material, thats a thing i didnt think of, how can i check if it is the arduino? I have accessonly to a breadboard, wires and the sd breakout

Comment: Was your original SD card that worked also 8 GB and formatted by FAT? I will add some more items in my answer (for you and possibly others).

Comment: First time i used and worked it was a 8 GB micro SD HC, it worked before and after i formated it. So i guess now i will try a new SD breakout board.

Comment: If you ruled out that all other components are still working, probably yes I'm afraid.